# How to align list items this way?

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulty aligning things correctly on the nav-bar. I want the words (home, players, about, contact) to be vertically aligned to the middle of the heart logo.

This is what it looks like now:

[image: img1]

I want it to look like this (did it on Photoshop)

[image: img2]

The code I have right now is:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Header */

header {
  background: black;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: #fe1d61 4px solid;
}

header a {
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

header li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="players.html">PLAYERS</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/00nation_logo.png" width="60px"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Sorry if there has already been a question made about this same thing, but I tried looking it up and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this & change your li CSS:

```
header ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply vertical-align property on your image to move it to the middle of others.
Try this:

style="vertical-align: middle;"

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to add some more CSS like

```
header li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;   // add this line
    line-height: normal;      // add this line
}
```

> Check on Full Screen

Here you can check full Example

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Header */
header{
    background: black;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border-bottom: #fe1d61 4px solid;
}

header a{
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

header li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="Norwegian-based esports organization with teams in CS:GO, Rocket League, and many other games.">
    <meta name="author" content="@__jmarcelo__">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>00 Nation DNB | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="players.html">PLAYERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E-YiHwfXsAEAuiZ.jpg" width="60px"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```